# Auto select cascading multi-valued parameters in VS Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportparameter

I have a couple of multi-valued parameters in my report created using visual studio reporting services, one filtered against the other.

I want that each time there is any change in my first parameter drop-down list, the values appended in my second parameter drop-down list, when updated, must be auto selected by default.

As of now, I get the desired values in my second parameter drop-down list each time there is any change in my first parameter list. However,in some cases,the appended values in my second parameter list are not selected by default.

Please give suggestions to implement this functionality.

Comment: Phrasing requests in the imperative - such as "An early responds is awaited" - is unlikely to improve the responses that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

By design, it is not possible for SSRS to re-evaluate the default value(s) for a subsequent parameter *unless* the selected value is no longer in the valid values list, as can be seen from [this issue on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/268032/default-does-not-get-refreshed-for-cascading-parameters).

One possible workaround is to ensure that when the higher level parameter's selected value is changed, the selected value is no longer available in the valid values list for the dependant parameter - this technique is discussed in more detail [here](http://www.bp-msbi.com/2011/04/ssrs-cascading-parameters-refresh-solved/).